# PHP Undefined variable?

Tags: php, variables

I buy GeoIP Web Services to get the client country from there IP's for my database and they give me a php code to get response from there API to tell me witch country that IP from , here is the code they give it to me:

```
    $query = "http://geoip.maxmind.com/f?l=" . $license_key . "&i=" . $ipaddress;
$url = parse_url($query);
$host = $url["host"];
$path = $url["path"] . "?" . $url["query"];
$timeout = 1;
$fp = fsockopen ($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, $timeout)
        or die('Can not open connection to server.');
if ($fp) {
  fputs ($fp, "GET $path HTTP/1.0\nHost: " . $host . "\n\n");
  while (!feof($fp)) {
    $buf .= fgets($fp, 128);
  }
  $lines = explode("\n", $buf);
  $data = $lines[count($lines)-1];
  fclose($fp);
} else {
  # enter error handing code here
}
echo $data;
```

I get the $data value that told me where the $ipaddress from ...... but I get get an error: Undefined variable $buf ?

Comment: What exactly is unclear about the message? :P

Comment: Is $buf initialized?  i don't think you can concatenate an undefined variable to initialize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
$buf = '';
```

on top of your code

Answer (score 1):

change your code to:

```
$query = "http://geoip.maxmind.com/f?l=" . $license_key . "&i=" . $ipaddress;
$url = parse_url($query);
$host = $url["host"];
$path = $url["path"] . "?" . $url["query"];
$timeout = 1;
$fp = fsockopen ($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, $timeout)
        or die('Can not open connection to server.');

if ($fp) {
  fputs ($fp, "GET $path HTTP/1.0\nHost: " . $host . "\n\n");
  $buf = ''; //This is the line of code that initializes $buf and will keep the undefined error from happening 
 while (!feof($fp)) {
    $buf .= fgets($fp, 128);
  }
  $lines = explode("\n", $buf);
  $data = $lines[count($lines)-1];
  fclose($fp);
} else {
  # enter error handing code here
}
echo $data;
```